# Customize Reset password screen

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a application registerd in Azure AD B2C, When new user logs in for the very first time he is redirected to the attached screen for updating the password. The issue here is that the user does not know what combination of password he needs to input untill and unless a specific combination works.
I need to customize this screen to display user friendly lable telling the user what combination of password he/she needs to enter on this screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJnK8.png)

Comment: That does not look like an AAD B2C screen, that looks like an AAD UX. The AAD UX is not customisable.

Answer (score 1):

With AAD B2C you can customize the user interface, which including the sign-up/sign-in, profile editing and password resetting experiences. This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview) outlines how to do the UX customization, test out the templates in the portal and has a few tutorials on setting it up.

Here are the specifics on [password rule enforcement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-password-complexity).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look at the documents and respond back.